# Android soft input behavior for KEYBOARD_12KEY, KEYBOARD_QWERTY, and KEYBOARD_NOKEYS

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method, android-hardware-keyboard

I was wondering if anybody here knows in what scenarios will Android show the user an on-screen soft keyboard, and how Android takes into account the different types of hardware keyboards available (`KEYBOARD_12KEY`, `KEYBOARD_QWERTY`, and `KEYBOARD_NOKEYS`).

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration#keyboard

#### Question (PART 1) - Could someone please fill out the following

Note that `??? = [show | hide | do nothing | other]`

Scenario 1)
User clicks on a `AppCompatEditText` and has `KEYBOARD_NOKEYS`, Android will `???` soft input

Scenario 2)
User clicks on a `AppCompatEditText` and has `KEYBOARD_12KEY`, Android will `???` soft input

Scenario 3)
User clicks on a `AppCompatEditText` and has `KEYBOARD_QWERTY`, Android will `???` soft input

#### Question (PART 2) - Is it possible to disable this built-in behavior

Now that you have filled in all the blanks of `??? = [show | hide | do nothing | other]`, is it possible to disable these built-in Android behaviors? And instead replace them all with custom versions by manually detecting the hardware keyboard type on the device and showing/hiding the soft keyboard inside a `View.OnFocusChangeListener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether to display the soft keyboard is actually decided by the soft keyboard.  The soft keyboard has a function InputMethodService.onEvaluateInputViewShown().  This function is called when there's a chance to show the soft keyboard.  If it returns true, the keyboard will be shown.  The default implementation is to look and see if a hardware keyboard exists, and to not display if so.  But the soft keyboard can override that to display anyway.

All of this is totally up to the soft keyboard app-  whichever keyboard they're using (so behavior can change based on which keyboard the user prefers).  There's no way for anything else to override it.

Comment: Assuming they are just using the default Android soft keyboard, does that mean the soft input keyboard will only be shown in `Scenario 1`? And hidden in both `Scenario 2` and `Scenario 3`?

Comment: There is no "default Android soft keyboard".  Every OEM is free to install whatever they want.  There's a default behavior for InputMethodService, but there's no way to know what a particular keyboard, even the one Google tends to ship, overrides that function to do.  Trying to answer would be a stab in the dark.  Although show for scenario 1 is a fairly safe assumption.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. If possible, do you think you could provide a source/link for me to read up on and for confirmation about the behaviour of soft keyboards and input method managers?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#onEvaluateInputViewShown()   That's the softkeyboard method that gets called.  It describes the default behavior of the function, but any keyboard can override it

Comment: In the provided link, one of the first sentences is *The default implementation returns false when there is no hard keyboard*. Do you have any idea on what *no hard keyboard* means specifically? Just `state == KEYBOARD_NOKEYS`? - implying that `KEYBOARD_12KEY` and `KEYBOARD_QWERTY` would be inapplicable?

Comment: No hard keyboard means no physical keyboard.  That would be shown as KEYBOARD_NOKEYS.  I'm not 100% sure how a bluetooth attached keyboard would change that, its been too many years since I've used this function.

Comment: So a `KEYBOARD_12KEY` would still be considered a hardware keyboard by the default Android implementation?

Comment: .... I'm honestly not sure.  I tend to think not, as its just numerics.  But you'd need to find an actual 12 key device to test, which isn't a common thing.  Sorry, my last keyboard was written in 2013.

Comment: Do you have any other links you think might be helpful in understanding the functionality of Android keyboards? Before I close this question.